# Добавление файла с формі на сайте в свой гугл диск

Tags: google-drive

Я написал код, который может добавлять файлы в гугл диск. Настроил все свои данные в консоли гугл. Когда я пытаюсь добавить файл свой в гугл диск, он отлично отправляется, я получаю успешное сообщение

`File uploaded successfully: { kind: 'drive#file', id: '18h8aPg7PnM9mCsGOMF4QlF4HAw-Dx9xa', name: 'name.jpg', mimeType: 'image/jpeg' }`

Но сам файл отправляется не ко мне на диск, а не пойми куда. Кто сталкивался с таким? Я уже добавлял в папку гугл диск доступ с е-мейла client_email который прописал в credentials самой консоли гугла, но это мне не помогло. Кто может подсказать как именно в свой гугл диск файл грузить?

```js
import { google } from 'googleapis'
import fs from 'fs'
import { Readable } from 'stream'
import path from 'path'

const filePath = path.resolve('./key.json')

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: filePath,
    scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
})

const uploadFiles = async () => {
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync('public/name.jpg')
    const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth })

    drive.files.create({
        requestBody: {
            name: 'name.jpg',
            mimeType: 'image/jpg',
            parents: "1WZj-6PV6sschMMBUFZax-O8ImCqTE7uC"
        },
        media: {
            mimeType: 'image/jpg',
            body: Readable.from(fileContents)
        }
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('File uploaded successfully:', res.data);
    })
}
```